# How to locate an Asp.net core site on subpath

Tags: nginx, docker, asp.net-core

This are my first baby steps in Nginx, so any help would be great.

I have a small docker-compose application consisting of two containers:
nginx
upload

The Nginx port 80 is exposed on the host machine so that the Nginx is reachable from our intranet like so: www.mytest.net
I would now expose the asp.net core site "upload" on subpath of that address, like:
www.mytest.net/upload/

Currently, I am unable to achieve this, every URL etc. on upload will not work if I attempt to move it to the path upload and I'm unsure if I have  to configure NGINX, asp.net core or both differently.

Current config in Nginx.conf:

```
 location / {

            proxy_pass              http://upload:80;

            # The default minimum configuration required for ASP.NET Core
            # See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html?highlight=nginx#configure-a-reverse-proxy-server
            proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
            # Turn off changing the URL's in headers like the 'Location' HTTP header.
            proxy_redirect          off;
            # Forwards the Host HTTP header.
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
            # The Kestrel web server we are forwarding requests to only speaks HTTP 1.1.
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            # Adds the 'Connection: keep-alive' HTTP header.
            proxy_set_header        Connection keep-alive;
        }
}
```

Like I said, it works on "/", but if I use "upload" a simple form on the upload site doesn't work anymore, due to URL mismatches.

Comment: Read up on HttpContext.Request.PathBase and a new extension called UsePathBase. These help isolate the app root URL so it doesn't mess up your routes.

Comment: @Tratcher Thank you very much! I will do that. Would you kindly make an answer out of it, so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on HttpContext.Request.PathBase and a new extension called UsePathBase. These help isolate the app root URL so it doesn't mess up your routes.